# Trying to run 32bit windows game in wine on 64bit 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ati, wine, playonlinux, winetricks

I am trying to run Icewind dale2 from GOG.com in wine on ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I am using the AMD ATI binary blob display driver. Running the file command on /usr/lib32/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2 gives:

```
george@devbox:/usr/lib32/fglrx$ file libGL.so.1.2 
libGL.so.1.2: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
george@devbox:/usr/lib32/fglrx$
```

So I definetly have 32bit opengl. I am using latest Playonlinux and tried this on wine 1.4 and 1.5...

How can I force wine to use my opengl library?

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved this by accident. I started the game and then when I saw the mouse was moving so very jerky again I pressed alt+F4 this brought up a messagebox asking me if I wanted to leave the game. I accidentally pressed no and was back in the game. However this time it was silky smooth!

So yeah, no idea why but just glad it did work :)